# Share Screen - Azure Communication Services

Tags: azure-communication-services

The share screen always works but I always have the error below:

```
await this.call?.startScreenSharing();
```

azure:ACS:error 12/25/2020, 22:49:30:133 [CallClient] [JS.TsCalling.MediaAgent] ffffffff: MA/DeviceManager Active device not found, Device id from track: 'u22', known devices: [{"deviceId":"u5","label":"u6","kind":"audioinput","groupId":"u7","type":"microphone","guid":"u2","isSystemDefault":true},{"deviceId":"u23","label":"u24","kind":"audioinput","groupId":"u10","type":"microphone","guid":"u25","isSystemDefault":false},{"deviceId":"u8","label":"u9","kind":"videoinput","groupId":"u10","type":"camera","guid":"u3","isSystemDefault":true,"position":"u11"},{"deviceId":"u26","label":"u27","kind":"videoinput","groupId":"u28","type":"camera","guid":"u29","isSystemDefault":false,"position":"u11"},{"deviceId":"u12","label":"u13","kind":"audiooutput","groupId":"u14","type":"speaker","guid":"u4","isSystemDefault":true},{"deviceId":"u30","label":"u31","kind":"audiooutput","groupId":"u32","type":"speaker","guid":"u33","isSystemDefault":false},{"deviceId":"u34","label":"u35","kind":"audiooutput","groupId":"u36","type":"speaker","guid":"u37","isSystemDefault":false},{"deviceId":"u38","label":"u39","kind":"audiooutput","groupId":"u7","type":"speaker","guid":"u40","isSystemDefault":false}]}, {"aspectRatio":1.7777777777777777,"deviceId":"window:39192306:4","frameRate":15,"height":1080,"resizeMode":"crop-and-scale","width":1920,"cursor":"motion","displaySurface":"window","logicalSurface":true}, {"maxWidth":1920,"minWidth":1920,"maxHeight":1080,"minHeight":1080,"fps":15,"deviceId":"display"}

Comment: Fernando, we would like to assist you further on troubleshooting this error. In order to do this, we will need Publicly Identifiable Information (PII), that would not be appropriate to share on a community forum. Can you please email me at azcommunity@microsoft.com? In the subject of the email please put ATTN: Bryan and in the body of the email, please include the resource ID and the subscription ID.